# Print My Search Results From SQL Server on label

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm just trying to print the sum of my search on a label in form.

Story is I have 2 textboxes that will give me 2 date and searching in my database, and printing the answer of sum cost between that 2 date.

My code is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SuperCalc;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();

        com = new SqlCommand("select sum (Cost) as JameKol From TBL_Cost Where CostDate between '" + textBox1.Text + "' and '" + textBox2.Text + "' ", con);
        label5.Text = com();

        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Search is done", "Done");
    }
}
```

com can't use as a method, so, how can I do this?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) which is exactly what this for. It gets first column of the first row which fits `SUM` function.

```
label5.Text = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

By the way, looks like your `CostDate` column is character typed. Don't do it. [This is a bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). You should **never** keep your `DateTime` values as a character. Change it to `datetime` or better `datetime2` type and pass your `DateTime` values *directly* to your parameterized query. That's why I used `DateTime.Parse` to parse your `Text` values. If it *can't* parse them, you can use `ParseExact` as well.

```
string conString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SuperCalc;Integrated Security=True";
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var com = con.CreateCommand())
{
    com.CommandText = @"select sum (Cost) as JameKol From TBL_Cost 
                        Where CostDate between @date1 and @date2";
    com.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    com.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    con.Open();
    label5.Text = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. it works, I'm sorry for my simple and beginner question, I'm so amateur in programming and just trying to learn more.

Comment: @RastinRadvar Glad to help. Don't worry about that. We _all_ pass the same steps. Just keep it up 